# How to shift my dataset to all positive values before applying BoxCox

Tags: python, data-transformation

I am trying to apply `boxcox()` function to my dataset but it shows an error saying data must be positive. How can I make my data positive? I have 1009 observations and 58 features. In R I just use this code and it works:

```
segPP <- preProcess(segTrainX, c("BoxCox", "center", "scale"))
segTrainTrans <- predict(segPP, segTrainX)
```

I need to do similar thing in Python but first I need to deal with negative values.

Comment: You could use Yeo-Joshnson transform, is another power transformation that can deal with zero and negative values, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Yeo-Johnson_transformation)

Comment: thanks Matteo, I wish I could use other transformations but my teacher has asked us to BoxCox transformation :(

Comment: You could add some value to them all

Comment: Cube root, neglog -- sign(x) * log(1 + |x|) -- and asinh() are examples of transformations that apply regardless of the sign of x and indeed preserve it. The big disadvantages of working with transforms of (x + constant) such that x + constant is positive include (1) being very sensitive to the choice of constant, (2) being difficult to compare with other variables in which the constant may be different, and (3) lacking subject-matter interpretation. Only if the origin is completely arbitrary does it make much sense to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [boxcox1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox1p.html)

```
from scipy.special import boxcox1p

df_boxcox = df.apply(lambda x: boxcox1p(x,0.25))
```

Comment: This only helps if all values are > - 1, does it not?