Negative values Box-Cox
I have a dataset and have developed a regression model. The linear assumption is not fulfilled and I have therefore made a BoxCox transformation. Some of the dependent variables were negative and in order to make the transformation a constant was added to make all dependent variables positive. After the optimal lambda has been found, I now thought of making a Q-Q plot and examining residuals with, among other things, Cook's distance and Studentied residuals to compare with the results from before the transformation. should I use the "old dependent variables" (i.e. those that are both positive and negative) when I do variable^lambda - 1 / lambda or should I use those that are positive (variable + constant) ?

Strongly related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310931/how-to-shift-my-dataset-to-all-positive-values-before-applying-boxcox/646416#comment1209744_646416 Answers argue that adding a constant may not be a good idea applying Box-Cox in situations with negative values..
